# Allow/Pass null values in Python-Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, null

I have a function like below:

```
def check(*args):
    return args[0] in args[1]
```

What I want to do is allow something like Y, N, “”

How do I pass or allow null/empty values in this?

It works for just Y, N fine. Thank you!

I tried to pass the below but couldn’t see the null values in the output.

```
Y, N, ‘’
Y, N, “”
Y, N, None
```

Comment: I think what you are looking for is try/except, Also your function only returns the first 2 positional arguments

Comment: If you are passing something like `["Yes", "None", "A value", "Other value", None]` then I think it is missing a `:` there... `return args[0] in args[1:]`

Comment: How is this related to pandas? What are you doing with the function? Please, provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
def check(value_to_check, *values):
    return value_to_check in values

result1 = check('Y', 'Y', 'N', '')  # returns True
result2 = check('', 'Y', 'N', '')    # returns True
result3 = check('A', 'Y', 'N', '')   # returns False
result4 = check(None, 'Y', 'N', None) # returns True

print(result1)  # Output: True
print(result2)  # Output: True
print(result3)  # Output: False
print(result4)  # Output: True
```